# boundary of a simply connected, compact manifold with boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, connectedness, manifolds-with-boundary

For a simply connected, compact n-manifold with boundary (n > 1), is its boundary connected?

It’s obviously false when n = 1, but how to prove or disprove the statement when n > 1? I’m especially interested in n = 2. Thanks.

Comment: Closed means compact without boundary, i think you only want compact.

Comment: @ecrin I think, in topology, “closed” usually means compact. Nonetheless, I do mean compact manifolds.

Comment: No, it means compact without boundary: [Closed manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold)

Comment: The word "closed" is used ambiguously in topology. When applied to a subset of a topological space, it means "the complement is open". When applied to manifolds, it means "the manifold is compact and its boundary is empty". It is indeed unfortunate that some subsets of topological spaces are themselves manifolds :-(

Comment: @LeeMosher my understanding is that the default meaning of manifolds is those without boundary; for those with boundary, we will explicitly say “manifolds with boundary”. Thus, when we say “closed manifolds (with boundary)“, in this phrase, “closed” means compact as the information of w/o boundary is already included in the other part of the phrase

Comment: You are right to point out a disconnect in the terminology of "manifolds" versus "manifolds with boundary", which makes things doubly confusing. Nonetheless, the terminology of "closed manifold" itself is unambiguous: it means "a manifold that is compact and has empty boundary". I would also suggest the terminology "closed manifold (with boundary)" invites the reader to get lost in ambiguities and disconnections and should therefore be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times[0,1]$ is a counterexample for $n>2$.

Comment: Any counter examples for n = 2?

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be a simply connected and compact $2$-manifold, hence a surface. According to "Riemann Surfaces" by Simon Donaldson (See [here](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Eskdona/RSPREF.PDF), Chapter 7, page 92), we have the following inequality for surfaces:
$$b_0(\partial X)\leq 2-\chi(X),$$
where $b_0(\partial X)$ (zeroth Betti number) denotes the [number of path-connected components](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Zeroth_homology_is_free_on_set_of_path_components) of $\partial X$. We need to compute those for $X$ to compute its Euler characteristic:

- Since $X$ is simply connected and therefore [per definition](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Simply_Connected) path-connected, we have $b_0(X)=1$.
- Since $X$ is simply connected, we have $H_1^\text{sing}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong\pi_1(X)^\mathrm{ab}\cong 1$ and therefore $b_1(X)=0$.
- Since the Betti number are the ranks of their respective homology groups, we have $b_2(X)\geq 0$.
- Since $X$ is a $2$-manifold, we have $b_n(X)=0$ for $n>2$.

We therefore have:
$$\chi(X)=b_0(X)-b_1(X)+b_2(X)\geq 1$$
resulting in:
$$b_0(\partial X)\leq 1,$$
which proves that $\partial X$ is path-connected and therefore connected.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$
I believe that for $n=2$ there are no such manifolds $M$, at least if you require $M$ to be **orientable**. Assume such an $M$ exists and assume that we can decompose the boundary as $\partial M = U \sqcup V$, where now $U,V$ are connected $1$-manifolds. Then, using Poincaré-Lefschetz (which requires the orientability), we have the following commutative diagram, where the rows are long exact sequences of the pair $(M,\partial M)$:
\begin{CD}
\cdots @>>> H^1(M) @>>> H^1(\partial M) @>>> H^2(M,\partial M) @>>> \cdots\\
& @V\cong VV  @V\cong VV  @V\cong VV \\
\cdots @>>> H_1(M,\partial M) @>>> H_0(\partial M) @>>> H_0(M) @>>> \cdots\\
\end{CD}
Now we observe that:

- $H^1(M) \cong 0$, since $M$ is simply connected.
- $H_0(M) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, since $M$ is in particular connected.
- $H_0(\partial M) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, by definition of $\partial M$.

It follows that $H_1(M, \partial M) \cong 0$ and hence by exactness the homomorphism
$$
H_0(\partial M) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z} \cong H_0(M)
$$
is injective. But this is a contradiction, because there are no injective homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$.

I hope this was helpful!

**Edit**: As user ecrin points out, the orientability of $M$ follows from it being simply connected. Then my proof should work in general.

Comment: It is surely oriented: otherwise, it admits a connetted $2:1$ covering which is orientable, contradicting the simply connectedness.

Comment: @ecrin Ah, that's true, I forgot about this fact. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more geometrically flavored argument for the case $n=2$. Let $M$ be a simply connected, compact $2$-manifold with boundary. Its boundary $\partial M$ is a compact $1$-manifold (without boundary), hence it has finitely many components, each homeomorphic to $S^1$ by the classification of $1$-manifolds. If $S^1\cong N\subseteq\partial M$ is such a component, we can form the manifold $M\cup_ND^2$, which is a compact $2$-manifold with one less boundary component. Furthermore, it is the union of embedded copies of the simply connected $M$ and $D^2$ intersecting along an embedded copy of the path-connected $S^1$, so it is simply connected (to be rigorous, one has to use collar neighborhoods here). Repeating this step finitely many times, we obtain a simply connected, compact $2$-manifold $M^{\prime}$ without boundary, so $M^{\prime}\cong S^2$ by the classification of surfaces. Now, working backwards, we see that $M$ is $S^2$ with a finite number of open disks having disjoing closures removed, i.e. it is has the homotopy type of a finitely punctured sphere (the number of punctures being the same thing as the number of boundary components of $\partial M$). However, this homotopy type is simply connected if and only if the number of punctures is $0$ or $1$, so $\partial M$ is connected. More precisely, this argument shows that $M\cong S^2$ or $M\cong D^2$.